# How to store IP Address and very large int account numbers in list? What types are best

Tags: sharepoint-online, splistitem, site-column, number, field-type

I'm making a list and need to store **IP Addresses and Account Numbers**.

Basically the text or single line of text variable looks best at the moment however I am wondering if anyone else knows a better way to store them in a SharePoint 2013 list.

I doubt an upgrade to IPv6 will happen, but the 16 places are necessary for the account number size(0123456890123.)

Comment: I found that I was just trying to go out of my way for no reason in storing the list data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single line of text can store 255 characters. So you will be good even in case of IPv6.

One drawback of storing interger in text field is that you will lose the out of the box ability to apply mathematical functions like SUM etc.

Comment: As for performance issues.. You don't have any control over the SQL server database.. Last time I looked was SP2003.. back then everything in the Tables was a (large) String. If you limit your Field in SharePoint it is a SharePoint (UX) limitation only..

Comment: I don't understand, so I shouldn't bother with anything but Text field types unless I really have to?

Comment: You can store any type of value into a text field. The maximum characters allowed is 255. If if want to store more than 255 character value then use multiline.